# utilisation de l'expression : "faire des siennes"

Tags: usage

Je me demande quelle est l'expression la plus appropriée pour remplacer "faire des siennes" quand le sujet est au pluriel. Car il me semble que "faire des leurs.." est peu usité.
Par exemple : " Cette nuit, ma fille a encore fait des siennes..." en parlant d'un bébé qui a empêché ses parents de dormir par ses pleurs.
Alors, cette nuit, les jumeaux ...? "

Toujours dans le même contexte, pourrait-on dire : " Les jumeaux ont été pénibles toute la nuit...? Ou : "les jumeaux ont encore dérangé ?

Answer (score 2):

On peut très bien dire *faire des leurs*, *faire des vôtres*,  etc..., même si *faire des vôtres* est plus rare.

Voir le *[TLF](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/v%C3%B4tre)* qui dit que :

> 2. Des vôtres, subst. fém. plur., rare, dans la loc. faire des vôtres (plus usuel à la 3<sup>e</sup> pers. faire des siennes, ils ont fait des leurs)

Si ça te parait bizarre tu peux employer une autre expression. Mais pour bien la choisir il faut savoir que le sens de l'expression *faire des siennes* a évolué et peut encore être compris de façons différentes.

L'expression qui est apparue au 16<sup>e</sup> siècle s’employait au départ pour parler de quelqu'un qui faisait des folies, des fredaines (*Dictionnaire culturel en langue française*).
On l'emploie encore dans ce sens là de nos jours mais encore plus souvent pour vouloir parler d'un comportement qui sort de l'ordinaire mais qui est habituel chez la personne de laquelle on parle. C'est de sens dans lequel tu l'emploies.

- Mes filles ont encore fait des leurs/des folies/des bêtises/désobéi, elles sont rentrées à 3 heures du matin.
- Les jumeaux ont encore fait des leurs/pleuré toute la nuit/nous ont embêtés toute la nuit.

*Faire des caprices* pourrait parfois convenir mais je ne le propose pas pour le dernier exemple, parce que si un enfant pleure ce n'est pas un caprice c'est qu'il a une raison (il fait ses dents, il fait des cauchemars...) mais là je m'éloigne de la langue !

> pourrait-on dire : « Les jumeaux ont été pénibles toute la nuit...? Ou : "les jumeaux ont encore dérangé ? »

Oui, bien sûr, « les jumeaux nous<sup>1</sup> ont encore dérangés toute la nuit » donne la même idée que « les jumeaux nous ont encore embêtés ».
« Les jumeaux ont été pénibles » donne aussi bien l'idée qu'ils ont embêté leurs parents.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> C'est plus idiomatique de mettre *nous* ici, même si ce n'est pas strictement nécessaire.</sub>